# Image gallery with individual description in Umbraco

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I'm trying to create a gallery in Umbraco. All I want is to upload a bunch of pictures, write an optional description on each image, pull out the images with Razor, and finally place them on the site.

I can select many images using the Media Picker, then do this to pull them out:

```
var collection = Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>>("images");
foreach (var image in collection) {
    <img src="@image.Url" />
}
```

But if I use Media Picker, I cannot input a description on the image.

I have an idea, which is kind of stupid and slow: Create a child document type called `Image` on my `Gallery` document type. Each image content then has an image and a description. This would be a very annoying way to do it, though.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to the media section you can change the name of the images you have uploaded before and use it as the description. Or maybe add a description field on the mediatype image (if it's a long text).

```
<img src="@image.Url" alt="@image.Name" />
<img src="@image.Url" alt="@(image.GetPropertyValue<string>("description"))" />
```

Also there should be a flag in the DataType of the picker to add the "open" functionality to the picker, so you will be much faster in the process switching from content to the media tree

Comment: How do you add a description field on the mediatype image? The description is going to be longer than a name + I need to use the name in the back office.

Comment: Settings > Media Type > Image, or you can create your custom media type

Comment: Then I would have to upload each image individually, right?

Comment: I just want to use a multiselector like the Media Picker, together with a custom image type that has a description. I have tried adding a description Vorto type to my image now, and I have added some text to it, but when I do `@image.GetVortoValue("description")` it's empty. Any reason why, you think?

Comment: Okay fixed. So apparently I cannot do `<p>@image.GetVortoValue("description")</p>`. What I had to do instead is add the description to a variable above, then simply do `<p>@description</p>`. Weird. Thanks for the idea of using a custom property on the media type!